Pulling two-letter characters from string column in PLSQL using regexp
TIA for your help.
I'm looking for guidance pulling two sets of two-letter characters from a VARCHAR column.
The column is isolated to have the following text:
"category from XX to YY", where "XX" is a two-character code and "YY" is a different two-character code.
However, there are instances where the text looks like:
"category from to YY", where there isn't a first two-character code.
Can you help me isolate the instances where both of these two-character codes exist in the column?
I've tried the following but with no success:
select *
from table
where regexp_like(column_name, '.{2}\sto\s{2}')

and 

regexp_like(column_name, '.{2}\sto')

and regexp_like(column_name,'.{2}to')


column_name LIKE 'category from __ to __' ?

When there is no "from" two letter code, are there two spaces next to each other?  from  to YY as opposed to just from to YY?  If so, column_name NOT LIKE 'category from  %' or alternatively column_name > 'category from a' should be pretty efficient.

If it's that clearcut then the string length is all you need to check. If these are both known lengths in known positions you might want simple string functions all around for performance reasons.

case when length(cc) = 22 then substr(c, 15, 2) end as XX, right(c, 2) end as YY

Try:
^category\s+from\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}\s+to\s+[a-zA-Z]{2}$

See: regex101

Explanation

^: Start of string followed by ...
category\s+from\s+: literal "category from ". (You might use   or  + [to match only literal space] instead of \s+. I prefer using + to make the pattern more robust if, per chance multiple spaces exist.)
[a-zA-Z]{2}: Then two letter characters... (If you only ever have capital letters, consider [A-Z])
\s+to\s+: literal " to " ...
[a-zA-Z]{2}: and two more letter characters...
$: until the end of line.


Why \s+ rather than just \s?

@MatBailie So it is more robust. If the string is always exactly one space   or \s work fine too.

Then you should explain that in your answer, and have + in your alternative white space too

Why urgently use regex? It seems they just need simple LIKE logic, as mentioned in comments below the question.

Well the question is tagged as regex. So I assume, that OP would be interested in a regex answer.

Seems like the simplest solution is
category from (\w{2} )*to \w{2}

\w is a word character, equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].
See it working on regex101.com.
